# Trouble appending html from ajax response to DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

My table is displaying that it didn't find any results in the first row and at the next rows shows the results.. yet again if I try to filter my data by ID or another column or even search for something all my data disappears and only re-appears after I reload the page. Also it shows that 0 records are being shown but some records are showing. What could be the issue here?

Ex.:

[when the page is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D76r.png)

[after I filter by some column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrEQw.png)

Ajax code when loading page :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>CRUD_Controller/crud_getDataAll/nivel/niveis",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){

                //alert("sucesso - " + data);
                $('#example1 tbody').append(data);

            },
            error:function(xhr)
            {
                alert('Algo falhou, nao caregou a tabela. - ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

My Data Table Initialization :

```
$(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
});

//Portugues
$('#example1').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":    "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":    "Mostrar _MENU_ registos",
        "sZeroRecords":   "Não foram encontrados resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":    "Nenhum dado dísponivel nesta tabela",
        "sInfo":          "A mostrar registos de _START_ a _END_ de um total de _TOTAL_ registos",
        "sInfoEmpty":     "Mostrando registos de 0 a 0 de um total de 0 registos",
        "sInfoFiltered":  "(filtrado de um total de registos _MAX_)",
        "sInfoPostFix":   "",
        "sSearch":        "Pesquisar:",
        "sUrl":           "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "A carregar...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
            "sLast":    "Último",
            "sNext":    "Seguinte",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Ative para ordenar a coluna em ordem ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Ative para ordenar a coluna em ordem decrescente"
        }
    }
});
```

My Controller Case :

```
case 'niveis':
            $rows = $this->Administracao_model->getAllData($table_name);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><a href="#">#NIV' . $row->id . '</a></td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><span class="badge ' . $row->classe . '">' . $row->nome . '</span></td>';

                ($row->adicionar == 1) ? $adicionar = "Adicionar" : $adicionar = "";
                ($row->remover == 1) ? $remover = ", Remover" : $remover = "";
                ($row->alterar == 1) ? $alterar = ", Alterar" : $alterar = "";
                ($row->pesquisar == 1) ? $pesquisar = ", Pesquisar" : $pesquisar = "";

                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center">' . $adicionar, $remover, $alterar, $pesquisar . '</td>';

                if($row->id == 1){
                    echo '<td class="align-middle text-center" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Não é possível remover o nível 0 do sístema."><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger text-white btn-sm disabled" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
                }else{
                    echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger text-white btn-sm" onclick="showModalCerteza(' . $row->id . ')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            break;
```

Please help, I tried switching the append() to HTML() but still, the table loses its data when searched or filtered.

Comment: If you want to populate a DataTables table with JSON from an Ajax call, then I recommend using the Ajax functionality built into DataTables.  See [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) for a brief overview, and also, for more examples using Ajax-sourced data, see [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html).

Comment: I was aiming for some way to filter my data table by using the HTML data response I have  inside the Ajax function or to append.

Comment: OK - understood. And yes, you can process the JSON data from the Ajax response in any way you wish, before it is displayed in a DataTable. And you can, as another example, use [column formatters](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) - all working within DataTables, instead of outside of it. The point is: all this can (and generally should) be done by DataTables. Otherwise you run into exactly the type of problem you are having: data mysteriously disappears - because you are trying to add data to the DOM/HTML table, outside of DataTables's control.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how it all works.. because the examples the site gives is very different from what I'm doing!

Comment: I tried adding 
`var table = $("#example1").DataTable();
    table.fnAddTr(data);`
after the Ajax response but it doesnt seem to recognize the comand. gives an Uncaught TypeError: table.fnAddTr is not a function

Comment: That is how I started, also. All I can suggest is: Create a _very simple_ first version. One which only displays the raw data via Ajax in a DataTable. Remove _everything else_. Make sure that is working. Then add one small enhancement. Make sure that is working. Repeat...

Comment: Can you add your JSON data to the question? If it is large, just add a small representative sample, but one which shows the overall structure.

Comment: I'm not working with JSON Data, my controller returns an HTML to the Ajax request that's why I'm appending the response data to the table.

Comment: I am sorry - I should have noticed that at the very start. My apologies. I have not seen any good way to make this approach work with DataTables - only with JSON.

Comment: Alright thank you for the effort!